# Which Desktop Environment has (or can have) global menus (apart from Unity)?

Tags: software-recommendation, desktop-environments, appmenu, maximized

In Unity global menus auto-hide, which is completely nuts. – But in general I like the functionality for maximized windows (as long as it doesn’t disappear).

Which DE can do global menus *and* has them:

- permanent (no timeout)
- for maximized windows only?

Answer (score 1):

What I’ve read:

- **Super Wingpanel** (not a DE) can can do that task
- [**gnome-globalmenu**](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/) does it for Gnome2 and now also Gnome3

I have no idea yet if they can be configured to the limitations mentioned in the question (maximized windows, no timeout).

Comment: Super Wingpanel is most often added to elementary OS installations (i.e., Pantheon DE).